# Does Katalon studio add on work on firefox latest version?

Tags: selenium, testing, automation, browser-automation, katalon-recorder

while checking for the add on for katalon in firefox, I am not able to find Katalon Recorder(Selenium IDE for firefox ). The only option is Katalon Recorder(Selenium IDE alternative). Is this both same? What should I do to perform record and playback using katalon for latest firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the correct add-on for Firefox
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/katalon-automation-record/

If you have any further questions on using Katalon Recorder, I highly recommend joining the official Katalon community
https://forum.katalon.com/